# JPA/Hibernate - saving the child without persist()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

As far as I understand ***persist(object)*** method - it should be used whenever we're saving a new object to the database (to make it managed an persistent).

In my example I have a **Book** class (parent) and a **Review** class (child) in **@OneToMany** relationship - One book has many reviews.

[image: MySQL tables]

Here are the classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Review> reviews;

    //skipping setters and getters

    public void addReview(Review review) {
        if(reviews == null) {
            reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();
        }
        reviews.add(review);
    }
}




@Entity
@Table(name = "review")
public class Review {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "comment")
    private String comment;

    //skipping setters and getters
}
```

My question is - how come can I add a review to the database without calling ***persist(review)*** but simply using book's method ***addReview(review)***?

Here is the method that adds the review to the associated book and to the database. All operations on this entity work normally - I can get the review, update it or remove it.

```
public void addReviewToBook(String bookTitle, String comment) {
        EntityManager em = ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY.createEntityManager();
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Book.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.ilike("title", bookTitle));
        Book book = null;
        try {
            book = (Book) cr.uniqueResult();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            //not calling em.persist(new Review(comment)) but only using addReview method
            book.addReview(new Review((comment)));
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Review added to the book");
        }
        catch (HibernateException e) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Could anyone explain it?

Comment: What do you think the `Cascade.ALL` doen when defininig the relation ship, on a side note, if you are using Spring I really don't hope you are using this code.

Comment: Thanks,  Cascade.ALL includes Cascade.PERSIST which performs persist() operation to the related entities. I'm not using Spring yet, but preparing to learn it.

Comment: I think you are confusing the concepts, when calling the addReview method you are adding an object to the property of another Java object, but then you must "send" that object to the database through the entity manager, using the persist or merge methods